# Qt creator 2 vertical splitters and fixed middle height

Tags: qt, layout, widget, qt-creator, splitter

I try create middle space with fixed height and disable hide behaviour for it. This screenshot of my test window:

[image: This screenshot of my test window]

As you can see, middle space too flat and can be hide when you drag it up or down to max position.

How to correct make this layouts behaviour?

EDIT:

[image]

Now I set min max height of this middle widget. This fix height. But how to disable hide behaviour?

EDIT 2:

I found it. splitter->setChildrenCollapsible(false)

This disable it for all. But I want disable it for middle widget only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you saw, splitter have the `setChildrenCollapsible`, but also a second one which is [`setCollapsible` (see QSpliter doc)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setCollapsible), letting you set this for a specific childre index.

In your case, the following code would be appropriate for the 2nd widget:

```
mySplitter->setCollapsible(1, false);
```